# Can the Australian funnel-web spider bite through fingernails?

Tags: entomology

[National Geographic](https://www.nationalgeographic.org/media/funnel-web-fangs/) says the following about the Australian funnel-web spider:

> The fangs of a funnel-web spider are very strong—they can pierce through shoe leather and fingernails.

I'm not skeptical about the shoe leather since leather is not a hard material. But fingernails are hard so I am skeptical of that part of the claim.

Comment: https://media.australianmuseum.net.au/media/dd/images/Spider.width-1600.735bca1.jpg

Comment: Do you really think fingernails are tougher than leather? My impression is the opposite. Fingernails are not as pliable, but they are thin, brittle, and permeable. I look forward to more authoritative answers to your question than my own speculation.

Comment: @PoloHoleSet: also, (human) fingernails have a relatively narrow thickness range, although in some cases, e.g. toe injury, you can get pretty thick (and semi-detached) ones...   "Shoe leather"  can have various thicknesses as well, esp. on less fancy boots, belts etc.

Comment: Near miss: [This author collected spiderbite cases](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0041010102003951) and reported a *different* (larger) Australian spider species had bitten through a fingernail.